# After I downloaded this recent 17.2.2 update, should I delete the 17.1.9 I had downloaded a few months ago?

Tags: update, download

I just logged into my Gui and it suggested I sownload the 17.2.2 update. I did, I think I did it right. I don't know. It's syncing right now but it's syncing from the 2155416 and going pretty slow. I was enjoying the syncing within 5 to 15 mins the past couple months after I finally got everything figured out and the blockchain downloaded and yes, it's been nice! Love XMR! Anyway, I just did this new update and I don't know if I did it right. I renamed something, but it still shows something to with the old name folder and when I opened the gui it now started all way back like it did couple months ago when I was having trouble. I guess I'll let it just sync for a day or 2 and hopefully I'll get back where I was. It IS showing my correct funds! while it's syncing, I'm happy about that. The GUI is showing the new name I put on the update as it's "path" but I don't know. I was wondering if I could delete all the stuff from the old 17.1.9 or whatever it was before this new 17.2.2 I just updated to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've updated, there's no need to keep old versions.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you for the answer! So after downloading any new versions of the gui, I do not have to worry about old downloads. So should I delete them from my computer? All except for the new version? Thanks for help!